# Globbing not working as desired in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line

I am learning Linux Basics and I have found some unexpected behaviour

Here is the script

```
ls /home/shiv/Documents
Dhoni.txt
```

Now, I want to use globbing

```
cd /home/shiv/Documents
ls *txt 
Dhoni.txt
```

But, If I want to search for .jpg files as well then, I am getting an error

```
cd /home/shiv/Documents
ls *{txt, jpg} 
ls: cannot access '*{txt,': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'jpg}': No such file or directory
```

What is the right command to list both txt and jpg files?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
ls *{txt,jpg}
```

spaces are used to separate arguments, so the shell is treating `*{txt,` and `jpg}` as two arguments, trying to match them separately. `{` and `}` are treated literally instead of expanded to a range of possible matches.